# How can I convert ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<String> or ArrayList<Timestamp>?

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

Program ::

```
ArrayList<Object> DataList = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<BigDecimal> valueList = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();

ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Timestamp> dateList = new ArrayList<Timestamp>();

List<ArrayList<Object>> listDatas = getDetailsfromDB();
// Here we get list like
//  [[12,apple],[25, grape],[1,orange]] or
//    [[12,12/12/2013],[25, 11/11/2013],[1,10/10/2013]]

for( int i = 0; i < listDatas.size(); i++)
{
List<Object> temp = listDatas.get(i);
      valueList.((BigDecimal) temp.get(0));
    if( temp.get(1) instanceof String)
          stringList.add((String)temp.get(1));
    else if( temp.get(1) instanceof Timestamp)
           dateList.add((Timestamp)temp.get(1));
 }
```

This is the program am tried out. 
But i want to use the same list for both string and timestamp.
Is that possible or not ? If yes how ??

Comment: If you've got a pattern of two objects being returned from `getDetailsFromDB()`, why not just use a `Map<BigDecimal,Object>` instead of `List<ArrayList<Object>>`?

Comment: You can just do it like this - List<Object> listDatas = getDetailsfromDB(); There is no need to mention ArrayList,

Comment: But the BigDecimal value is not unique.

Comment: But I have problem in creating two list for string and timestamp..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to loop over it and convert each item into a new list of strings yourself.

```
 ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add("Java");
    list.add(3.14);

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Object object : list) {
        strings.add(object != null ? object.toString() : null);
    }
```

Comment: So what about the Timestamp ??

Comment: I am on it, I ll post it when done. Till then check for string. and post me back that is it working or not ?

Comment: thanks this works correctly . but i want to use one list instead of two lists (ie one for string and other for timestamp) .

Comment: I ll post it later, I am busy right now. Sorry for that but I have some urgent work to do so hope you can understand. accept the answer if it works, I ll post for TimeStamp later onwards.

Comment: It's my pleasure, Accept answer if solved by clicking on tick mark of answer.

Comment: But answer is not completed.

Comment: Ok doesn't matter. Your wish. I ll post answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate through all elements of the list and then will have to cast individual element to String. You can use Object toString() method for this purpose.

Better would be to create a separate method for converting object into String and Timestamp. Object is parent class for all classes in Java and hence can hold any object type. You can check the object type in that method and hence can create String and Date objects accordingly.

You can use the following code for casting object element to Timestamp -

Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);

Comment: thanks for the answer. My question regarding with the two lists that am used in my program. I want to replace that by one. but how?